# how to make flatlist component of react-native scroll to bottom when its first rendered?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build a Chat Application using react-native and using flatlist to display the messages. And i want my list to stay at bottom always can anyone plzz suggest me a solution.

Comment: Best option would be use `FlatList` in `inverted` mode, take a look at the doc https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#inverted

Answer (score 10):

Basically you need to use *scrollToEnd* on flatList..

First: create a *flatList* reference with:

```
ref={ (ref) => { this.myFlatListRef = ref } }
```

Second: add *onContentSizeChange* listener on flatList

```
onContentSizeChange={ () => { this.myFlatListRef.scrollToEnd({animated:true}) } }
```

Third: add *onLayout* listener on flatList for scroll to bottom when keyboard is showed.

```
onLayout={ () => { this.myFlatListRef.scrollToEnd({animated:true}) } }
```

eg:

```
<FlatList
    ref={ (ref) => { this.myFlatListRef = ref } }
    onContentSizeChange={ () => { this.myFlatListRef.scrollToEnd({animated:true}) } }
    onLayout={ () => { this.myFlatListRef.scrollToEnd({animated:true}) } }
    data={this.state.messages}
    renderItem={ ({item}) => <Item data={item} /> }
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to do this is to use `inverted` props in the flatlist 
this allow us to render list up-side-down

for more ref. vidit https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#inverted

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can do this -

```
const  messageData  = this.props.convo
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

            <FlatList 
              inverted={-1}
              style={styles.list}
              extraData={this.props}
              data={messageData}
              keyExtractor = {(item) => {
                return item.id;
              }}
              renderItem=   
              {this.renderItem}           
              />
```

after that, you will get an inverted list which will have the topmost elements in the list, so for fixing this you can add `reverse()` in your flatlist data or in your reducer. Like this-
`data={messageData.reverse()}` or in reducer `return { ...state, chats: action.payload.reverse() }`

Answer (score -1):

You can give a `ref`to `FlatList` and access certain flatList properties that can scroll at particular position. Here below resolution should work.

```
setTimeout(() => this.refs.flatList.scrollToEnd(), 200)
```

[ScrollToEnd React native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#scrolltoend)